# Issue with Load Balancing WCF Services on Server 2012 R2

Tags: amazon-web-services, wcf, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

We recently upgraded our servers to Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5 and are now having a problem with our WCF Services when they are load balanced. If one of the servers is not in the load balancer we are able to call the WCF service. The moment we have both Servers in the load balancer we get either Security Negotiation failure or Endpoint address Exceptions.

The WCF Services were previously load balanced on Server 2008 and Server 2012 with IIS 7.5.  Nothing has changed with our WCF Services and yet with Server 2012 R2 we keep getting the above mentioned errors. We have also ensured all settings we had set on the previous server environment is the same for the 2012 R2 environment and IIS 8.5.

We do not have sticky sessions enabled and have never needed to have it enabled in order to load balance the WCF Services. We have turned them on for Server 2012 R2 however this did not solve the issue we are having and have since turned it off again.

Are we missing something that needs to be set on our side with Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8.5?

Comment: What binding are your services using?

Comment: I am using a customBinding of wsHttpBinding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found the issue. There was a difference between our old server and current server environment.

We are using AWS to load balance the servers and there is a setting "Cross Zone Load Balancing" that was enabled with the new server Environment, and was disabled with the old server environment. The setting ensures even load across our load balanced servers

This was quite a surprise as i was under the impression that WCF Services were stateless unless set to use a session. It turns out the binding we are using requires server affinity. Which is why we were getting the errors.